# PIXI Sprite displays in black

Tags: pixi.js

I am trying to set a `Sprite` as a background in my viewport. The `grid.png` is 23040 x 9984 pixels.

```
   this.app.loader
      .add("grid", require("./assets/grid.png"))
      .load((loader, resources) => {
        const grid = new PIXI.Sprite(resources.grid.texture);
        grid.anchor.set(0, 0);
        grid.scale.set(1);
        this.container.addChild(grid);
      });
```

The `Sprite` shows in my `Container` but only in black. If I try with a smaller png (25 x 25 pixels) it works.

I also made sure my viewport world `width` and `height` were big enough :

```
   this.viewport = new Viewport({
      screenWidth: 953,
      screenHeight: 409,
      worldWidth: 25000,
      worldHeight: 10000,
      interaction: this.app.renderer.plugins.interaction 
    });
```

Here is the sandbox code 
https://codesandbox.io/s/pixi-sprite-loading-cn7re?file=/src/App.vue:572-875

Answer (score 0):

1. You see sprite as black (in chrome) because is too big and you add it using "require":

```
.add("grid", require("./assets/grid.png"))

this does basically following:

.add("grid", "data:image/png;base64,iVBORwA<MoreBase64StringHere>")
```

which is too much for browser when grid.png has such big dimensions.

You should add it by passing url to the image - instead of requiring whole inlined image:

```
      .add({
        name: "grid",
        url: "grid-small.png",
        crossOrigin: "anonymous"
      })
```

Note that `grid-small.png` should be in "public" dir of codesandbox, and `crossOrigin: "anonymous"` is to avoid problems with cross-origin when image is loaded.

2. Such big images (especially if it consist basically many copies of same image) should be avoided. You should try using for example some small/medium chunk of the image (the mentioned `grid-small.png`) and `TilingSprite` technique. In such way you can easily have 25000 x 10000 grid - as you can see in codesandbox below.
3. You shouldnt keep Pixi objects inside Vue component state - i already told you in other post about it ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/62094101/3174731 ) - you are not listening ;) . Why do you want Vue to analyze Pixi objects? Is not its job. Vue should be about what is going on in DOM etc - not about whats in canvas. See codesandbox linked below how much faster everything is if you keep Pixi related objects outside of Vue component (`myPixi` variable).

You can see how above optimizations work in following codesandbox (modified version of yours) : https://codesandbox.io/s/pixi-sprite-loading-3vsne?file=/src/App.vue